# Pymongo Converting command cursor to list in batches of 5000

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to load large set records from mongodb to pandas and I want to do it in batches of 5000. with `pymongo Command cursor` I could get the first 5000 records but I don't know how to switch to next 5000.

Ultimately what I want to do is

```
def load_data(command_cursor): 
   pd.DataFrame(list(command_cursor))
```

But this on large volumes of data freezes my system so I want to do it in batches

```
if num_records > 5000:
        df = json_normalize(list(records.batch_size(5000)))
        while records.alive:
            try:
                records.next()
            except:
                break
            df.append(json_normalize(list(records.batch_size(5000))))
else:
    df = json_normalize(list(records))
return df
```

The `alive` attribute is always `False` and `next` always throws `StopIteration`